# How can I set/provide a default value while django migration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

**Scenario**:
 I have a model, `Customer`

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and now I updated the `company` attribute witha `ForeignKey` relationship as below,

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

What I need is, when the new migrations applied to the DB,corresponding `Company` instance must automatically generate and map to the `company` attribute of `Customer` instance.
Is that possible? How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's start from your original model and do it step by step.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

First you would have to keep the original field and create a new one, to be able to restore the old data afterwards.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    _company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Now you can create a first migration with `manage.py makemigrations`. Then you will have to create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/writing-migrations/). Create the migration using `manage.py makemigrations yourapp --empty` and update the generated file:

```
from django.db import migrations

def export_customer_company(apps, schema_editor):
    Customer = apps.get_model('yourapp', 'Customer')
    Company = apps.get_model('yourapp', 'Company')
    for customer in Customer.objects.all():
        customer._company = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=customer.company)[0]
        customer.save()

def revert_export_customer_company(apps, schema_editor):
    Customer = apps.get_model('yourapp', 'Customer')
    Company = apps.get_model('yourapp', 'Company')
    for customer in Customer.objects.filter(_company__isnull=False):
        customer.company = customer._company.name
        customer.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourapp', 'xxxx_previous_migration'),  # Note this is auto-generated by django
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(export_customer_company, revert_export_customer_company),
    ]
```

The above migration will populate your `Company` model and `Customer._company` field according to `Customer.company`.

Now you can drop the old `Customer.company` and rename `Customer._company`.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Final `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Almost! `customer._company = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=customer.company)
` wont work as get_or_create returns a tuple with `(object, created)`

Comment: Can I have to ask you something, what's the purpose of `noop()` method?

Comment: This is a method that does nothing. Which means there is nothing to do when reversing the migration. I invite you to read the link I posted about migration. Everything I used is detailed here. :)

Comment: I applied the migrations as you said. Then I reverted to zero, ( `python manage.py app_name zero`) .Then I migrated again, ath this point I got some `operational error`

Comment: Did the migrations work in the first place? Any reason why you reverted to zero? What migration caused the operational error? The details of the operational error would be welcome.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard Migrations are migrated forward direction, ( `0010 -> 0011 -> 0012 -> etc` ).  But, I'm little bit curious about `worst case scenario`  :P That's why I'm thinking about  revert condition too

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example of reverse code. About your migration issue, we don't have enough information to help you. I'd suggest you open another question for that one rather than solving this in comments.

Comment: What kind of worst case scenario are you trying to test?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but you have to do three migrations and the fields cant be named the same thing as both need to exist at the same time. If you already have removed the company field in your real database you are SOL and will have to fix them manually.

First, add the `Company` model in a normal db migration, then do a data migration and have it run after the first db migration, then do another db migration removing the company field from the `Customer` model.

The db migrations you can do with `manage.py makemigrations` as usual, just add something like below in a migration file between them, here i named the new company `ForeignKey` field to `company_obj`

```
def fix_companies(apps, schema_editor):
    Company = apps.get_model("myapp", "Company")
    Customer = apps.get_model("myapp", "Customer")
    for c in Customer.objects.all():
        company, _ = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=c.name)
        c.company_obj = company
        c.save()


def rev(apps, schema_editor):
    # the reverse goes here if you want to copy company names into customer again if you migrate backwards.
    pass

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', 'XXXX_migration_that_added_company_model'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(fix_companies, rev),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to note is if you are going through a cycle of renaming/ deprecating fields, using `RunPython` would leave you pointing to old model fields that wouldn't exist anymore after you are done with your field changes.

To avoid this, you might want to go with `RunSQL` instead.

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.3 on 2022-02-09 04:55

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("<your_app>", "<0006_migration_name>"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(f"""
update public.<table_name> set new_field = old_field + some_magic;
"""
        ),
    ]
```

[Docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)