# How to remove custom field without breaking Django migrations?

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-jsonfield

I work on a Django 1.8 project that uses the old [django-json-field](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field) library. I want to remove the library, update to Django 1.9 and use the native JSONField, but I have migrations that rely on the JSONField from the old library, so I can't remove it. I also can't update Django without removing it because it is deprecated and causes errors when I try to update Django. What's the correct way to proceed in this situation?

Comment: Use a `CharField` as an intermediate way to store the JSON?

Comment: Use [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython)

Comment: a similar RunPython example , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221515/how-can-i-set-provide-a-default-value-while-django-migration)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem has the right idea, since `django-json-field` is actually just a `TextField` wrapper (ref: [source](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield/blob/master/jsonfield/fields.py#L154))

Comment: @Ariel Does Django support native JSON? Can you share some reff?

Comment: Its only supported for postgresql; as it has a native json column type. For all others its just a text field wrapper with a custom serializer. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) for more details.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Burhan Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790387/burhan-khalid) on his comment above, a solution would be to

- Copy that deprecated json-field to a text column
- Create that migration
- Delete the deprecated json-field
- Create this migration
- With no trace of the deprecated json-field, remove the package. Test that everything is OK and upgrade your app.

If this doesn't work (probably because that json-field is referenced elsewhere) you'll have to just change that field to text in your models.py and then make it through migrations.